# Banner iOs push notification when app in foreground

Tags: objective-c, react-native, push-notification

Is it possible to trigger the display of a banner push notification when the app is running in the foreground, just as if it were in the background?

I am using React-Native version 41.2, and react-native-push-notification 2.2.1

I note from searching that it should be possible in iOs 10 by adding the following to the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
```

However, this does not seem to be getting hit, and instead are hitting the didReceiveLocalNotification methods like below:

```
// Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
[RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Does React-Native have access to the userNotificationCenter? Or is it possible to achieve similar results using the other methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get this working.

In the `AppDelegate.h` file, you need to import UserNotifications and set the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate like below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

Then in the `AppDelegate.m` file, you need to add `[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];` inside your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

You must then remove the `didReceiveLocalNotification` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` , as these appear to take precedence over the `userNotificationCenter`.

Then add the `userNotificationCenter`handler as below.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter* )center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification* )notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);

  }
```

Hope this helps some other react-native developers as unfamiliar with iOs development as I am.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 code ,ios 10 and above**

`import UserNotifications` in your appdelegate and set `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`
In your app's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function add

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

then the following UserNotificationDelegate method will be invoked when app receives a notification in foreground state and banner will be displayed

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```